# It's [high(est)] noon

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

A recent question just brought my attention to the [highest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highest) tag, which has 74 questions, no followers and only 15 questions (today) in the past **year**

Though its use is reasonably similar throughout questions, it is used for anything even slightly related, such as finding lowest values, second highest etc.

Comment: I think a synonym is in line if the questions are good.  Tag [tag:max] already exists.  Even better if we can find a tag that encompass stuff dealing with both [tag:max] and [tag:min], (and anything else that essentially means finding a value based on the upper or lower limit of a range

Comment: @psubsee2003 good idea, I was under the impression that it was an SQL tag, but looking at the wiki that's certainly a general tag

Comment: Even if they were SQL tags, the terms are so ambiguous that they could mean anything.  If there is need for SQL specific tags, we'd probably want to create a new tag and preface them with [sql-*] to uniquely identify them

Comment: @psubsee2003 there's a school that wants tags to read as titles: [sql][select][max][list][etc.]

Comment: Now I want to play Overwatch :(

Comment: Actually, there have been 15 questions posted this year from the tag. I think you read the dates wrong.

Comment: @4castle Nov 14 to Nov '14 in my head, my bad!

Answer (score 20):

This should definitely be burninated. In addition to not having a clear purpose, a vast majority of the questions on this tag have scores ≤0. I see no purpose to it and with no usage guidelines, there is no benefit or potential usage to it.